# Fastest way to iterate over n-dimensional array of arbitrary extents?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, multidimensional-array, n-dimensional

In C++ I wish to iterate an n-dimensional array with arbitrary extents ranging from min[n] to max[n] respectively, maintaining the ordinates in ord[n] respectively throughout.

Ie. a general solution to:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
for (int y = 3; y < 20; y++)
for (int z = -2; z < 5; z++)
...
   doSomething(x, y, z ...)
```

Of the form:

```
int min[n] {0,  3, -2 ...}
int max[n] {10, 20, 5 ...}
int ord[n] {0,  0,  0 ...};

int maxIterations = (max[0] - min[0]) * (max[1] - min[1]) * ....
for (int iteration = 0; iteration < maxIterations; iteration++)
   doSomething(ord)
   iterate(n, ord, min, max)
```

The fastest algorithm for iterate() I can think of is:

```
inline void iterate(int dimensions, int* ordinates, int* minimums, int* maximums)
{
    // iterate over dimensions in reverse...
    for (int dimension = dimensions - 1; dimension >= 0; dimension--)
    {

        if (ordinates[dimension] < maximums[dimension])
        {
            // If this dimension can handle another increment... then done.
            ordinates[dimension]++;
            break;
        }

        // Otherwise, reset this dimension and bubble up to the next dimension to take a look
        ordinates[dimension] = minimums[dimension];
    }
}
```

This increments and resets each ordinate as required, avoiding the callstack or any maths.

Is there are faster algorithm?

Comment: Have you measured the running time? Is `doSomething(x, y, z ...)` very fast? Shouldn't your first version (3 for loop) be unrolled by any decent compiler?

Comment: tgmath - yes a compiler might unroll a loop hard coded to 3 levels but I need a N-level loops where N is not known at compile time, plus I am currently working with 1 million+ iterations which could not be unrolled. I am interested in the optimization of the iterating algorithm rather than the optimization of doSomething().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you start doing something analogous to [Gray codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) which is going to change the order of your traversal (and potentially be very complex), you're pretty much at a point where it's as good as it's going to get. Actually, the amortized time of `iterate` is already `O(1)`, assuming each dimension has a minimum that is not equal to its maximum.

The worst case is when all `d` dimensions have `maximum = minimum + 1`. That is, every other increment of any particular dimension will spill into the next dimension(s). However, note that the total number of digit changes needed for a specific dimension `x` (from `1` to `d`) is `2^(d + 1 - x) - 1`. This is obviously less than `2^(d + 1 - x)`. Summing this over all dimensions (`1` through `d`) is a simple geometric sum which yields `2^(d + 1) - 2` which is obviously less than `2^(d + 1)`. Note the number of iterations is `2^d`, and hence the average time per iteration is a constant: `2^(d + 1) / 2^d = 2`.

If you really have to squeeze speed, probably the best it's going to get is low level tweaks:

- Is the number of dimensions known and less than a small (say, 20 or less) constant? Then you can eliminate the `for` loop by unrolling the loop. Your compiler may be smart enough to do this already if it can deduce that `dimensions` is constant, or you may have to create several versions of `iterate` with a constant dimension or with the loop unrolled manually. (You could use templating if you wanted to give it a nice API.)
- You can actually get rid of your maxIterations/iteration check in the *big* outer loop (the one that has the `doSomething` call in it) and allow your iterate function to change a boolean when it runs out of dimensions it can increase. This reduces your `for` loop to `while (keepGoing) { ... }`.
- It may be very slightly faster to pass an array of structures with each dimension's minimum and maximum, but I expect cache to mitigate the benefits almost entirely.

Of course, benchmark before and after any such changes -- every architecture and tool chain reacts differently.